# SyntaxError: Unexpected token {, ES6 Imports

Tags: typescript, webpack, serverless

I am using: serverless, serverless-offline, Typescript and serverless-webpack, although I believe this to be a webpack issue.

I am able to build using webpack and use the ES6 import syntax and continue to use this syntax in the files further related, e.g.

./src/handler.js

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-lambda';
```

this also works for locally defined modules.

However, very strangely, when I use this import syntax in src/entities/User.ts for example (and all modules in the entities directory I get this error).

```
import { Entity } from 'typeorm';
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
```

Webpack config:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const _ = require('lodash');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
/* eslint-enable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
    entry: _.assign({}, slsw.lib.entries),
    devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.mjs', '.json', '.ts'],
        symlinks: false,
        cacheWithContext: false,
        alias: {
            '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
            '@queries': path.resolve(__dirname, './queries'), // can do import { func } from '@queries/file'
            '@tests': path.resolve(__dirname, './tests'),
        },
    },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
            {
                test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: [
                    [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '.serverless'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
                    ],
                ],
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                    experimentalWatchApi: true,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.graphql$/,
                exclude: [
                    [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '.serverless'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
                    ],
                ],
                loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
            eslint: true,
            eslintOptions: {
                cache: true,
            },
        }),
    ],
};
```

Ts config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "inlineSources": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceRoot": "/",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@queries/*": ["queries/*"],
      "@tests/*": ["tests/*"]
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types"],
  },
  "files": ["src/@types/graphql.d.ts"],
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    ".serverless/**/*",
    ".webpack/**/*",
    "dist/**/*",
    "_warmup/**/*",
    ".vscode/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Why does this happen / how to fix?

Comment: Is this at runtime or compile time?

Comment: This was at runtime. The error was because Typeorm was using Files defined from its config file rather than referencing those files through code, leading to un-transpiled code being referenced.